# Merge two dimensions in Webi 4.0 report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a report query that returns two objects, one is a String and one is a Number, I would like to merge these dimensions but Webi does not allow me to do so and I guess it's because they have different types.

Is is possible to merge them?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you have two queries that you want to merge...

You will need to make a change to the universe, to create a new object that converts one of these objects to the other datatype.

Note that in BI4.2 SP3, there is a new feature that allows for data providers to be merged based on a variable rather than a query result column  That would help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter to you whether they end up as a string or a number? If not, create a variable to recode the string as a number within the report itself.
    =tonumber([string];"#")

You may have to change the contents within the quotation marks, depending on how your string is formatted.